# Modifying MS Access forms using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

If have an old Access DB front-end with hundreds of forms. I'm trying to update them en masse using VBA. I can do most things in VBA including open the form in design view, change the fonts and colors, but I can't figure out how to create or delete a control like a command button. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Public Sub ChgFormProps(Optional FormName As String, Optional ControlName As String)
Dim db As Database, Con As Container, Doc As Document
Dim frm As Form, ctl As Control, FormChgd As Boolean

Dim proNum As String, EM As errInfo: proNum = "001"
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:

FormChgd = False

Debug.Print "Changed Forms:"
Set db = CurrentDb
For Each Con In db.Containers
    For Each Doc In Con.Documents
        If Con.Name = "Forms" Then
            If FormName = Doc.Name Or FormName = "" Then
                DoCmd.OpenForm Doc.Name, acDesign
                Set frm = Screen.ActiveForm

                    For Each ctl In frm.Controls

                        If ControlName = ctl.Name Or ControlName = "" Then
                            Select Case ctl.ControlType
                                Case acComboBox
                                    ctl.FontName = "Segoe UI"
                                    FormChgd = True
                                Case acImage
            
                                Case acTabCtl
                                    ctl.FontName = "Segoe UI"
                                    FormChgd = True
                                Case acListBox
                                    ctl.FontName = "Segoe UI"
                                    FormChgd = True
                                Case acTextBox
                                    ctl.FontName = "Segoe UI"
                                    FormChgd = True
                                    
                                    If ctl.Locked = True Then
                                        ctl.BackColor = -2147483626
                                        FormChgd = True
                                    Else
                                        ctl.BackColor = WHITE
                                        FormChgd = True
                                    End If
                         
                                Case acCommandButton, acToggleButton
                                    ctl.FontName = "Segoe UI"
                                    If ctl.Name = "HelpCmd" Or ctl.Name = "CloseCmd" Then
                                        'do nothing
                                    Else
                                        ctl.FontName = "Segoe UI"
                                        ctl.ForeColor = BLACK
                                        ctl.BackColor = WHITE
                                        ctl.HoverColor = BLUE
                                        ctl.HoverForeColor = WHITE
                                    End If

                                    FormChgd = True
                                
                                Case acCheckBox
                                
                                Case acLabel
                                    ctl.FontName = "Segoe UI"
                                    ctl.ForeColor = 0
                                    FormChgd = True
                                    
                                    If ctl.Caption = "DELETE" Then
                                        Stop
                                    End If
   
                                Case acLine

                            End Select

                        End If
                    Next
      

                
                If FormChgd Then
                    DoCmd.Close acForm, Doc.Name, acSaveYes
                    Debug.Print Doc.Name
                    FormChgd = False
                Else
                    DoCmd.Close acForm, Doc.Name, acSaveNo
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next

ExitHere:
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    Select Case Err
        Case 2462
            Resume Next
        Case Else
            EM = ErrMsg(Err, objNum, proNum)
            fMsgBox EM.Msg, vbCritical, EM.Title
            Resume ExitHere
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: [Application.DeleteControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.deletecontrol) and [Application.CreateControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.createcontrol)

Comment: Well damn, that was simple. My brain just freezes sometimes. Thanks!

Comment: In MS Access, *hundreds* of any object (tables, queries, forms, or reports) suggest a subpotimal design. If such objects are similar in structure, reduce the number of such objects and dynamically pass data into them.

Answer (score 0):

That worked. Use Application.DeleteControl and Application.CreateControl as suggested by HansUp. Thanks!